# Unix curl to php curl convertion

Tags: php, json, bash, curl

I have the following bash curl command which returns the api results i want

```
 curl -v -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch' http://api.blabla.com?search_id=my_id --compressed
```

I am writing a PHP sdk for this API but i can not convert this curl command into php curl.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $resultsURL);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Connection: Keep-Alive');   
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); // number of seconds to allow curl to execute

$results = curl_exec($ch1);
echo(json_encode($results));
curl_close($ch1);
```

I get some results but they are inconsistent. The usual response is around 9MB of json (from the cli curl) and i get everything from 1.46KB to 900KB. All this happen on the same api call...

What can be wrong with this code or how can i get this done? I am out of ideas about it

**Edit:** after a long debug i found out that bash curl and php curl send the same request and it must be the servers (apache in my case) fault that it doesnt fetch everything back to me in the response.

I will edit again and post an answer when i find exaclty what it is.

Comment: You have 3 different calls to `curl_exec()`, is it actual or example code?

Comment: Try setting [`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: @Flying No, it was by mistake, i have one exec in my running code.

Comment: @GeorgeSp why do you use `json_encode()` for your response? It should be `json_decode()` I think?

Comment: Also suggestion from @kerbholz should be useful for you

Comment: @kerbholz I think this is irrelevant, RETURNTRANSFER is for displaying the response as a string. This is not my problem here.

Comment: @Flying you are right, but even with json_decode the actual result size does not change.

Comment: Try to not apply `json_decode()` and inspect returned result. I suspect that curl may return raw results and hence you may need to de-gzip it before receiving actual response. However I may be wrong of course, just a thought.

Comment: What errors/results are you getting? Is it just `true`/`false`? (Because `curl_exec()` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure)

Comment: @kerbholz I am not getting any errors, I don't get any true or false. $results returns the response of the curl_exec. Even without RETURNTRANSFER.

Comment: @GeorgeSp do your response, received from `curl_exec()` contains json or it is binary data? If it is json then there is hardly something wrong with your code, check what do you actually call and receive (for example by using wireshark or some other sniffer)

Comment: @Flying It does contain json. But i can not explain why it does not contain all the data it should. When i use curl from cli i get much more data than when i use curl from php. Could this be a php problem? Like a timeout? I tried both CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CUROPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT but nothing changed. I am frustrated with this...

Comment: @GeorgeSp try to save whole response in a file and examine how it ends. Is it complete and valid json file or is it cut in the middle? If it is complete file - then it is how information is received from server, if it is cut - then problem is somewhere else. Also, how long does your script runs? And where did it run from - console or web server?

Comment: @Flying It runs pretty quickly. I will do that, but . think it just returns a large json. So i can not tell if it is right or wrong.

Comment: @GeorgeSp if it runs fast then it is not a problem of timeout, but in a case of running it on web server you can also check for timeout from web server itself (e.g. in a case if php runs as apache module). If json is complete then it is not a problem with receiving data, so question goes to either request itself or a way, server handles it. I would propose to run some sniffer and look at actual http request / response. Sometimes it helps :)

Comment: I just noticed after the json there is a "1" which shouldn't exist. Could this be a decode error? I will proxy it through burp and try to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157129/discussion-between-flying-and-george-sp).

Answer (score 0):

php curl [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says for `CURLOPT_ENCODING`

> The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding
>   of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and
>   "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all
>   supported encoding types is sent.

So use empty there to support any encoding.

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: It must be something with the API you're using. I tested both curl on bash and a php script and I get the same result. Here's a pastebin with the PHP code I used: https://pastebin.com/pX0C4cnu